# How can you make a Client-Server with 2 different computers in the lan?

Tags: python, lan, nmap

It just times out for me , even if I use the gethostbyname method or gethostname for the private ip address....

Code:

```
def connect(self):
        nm = nmap.PortScanner()
        nm.scan(hosts = '192.168.1.0/24', arguments = '-n -sP -PE -PA21,23,80,3389')
        devices = []
        hosts_list = [(x,nm[x]['status']['state']) for x in nm.all_hosts()]
        for ip,state in hosts_list:
            devices.append(ip)
        for ip in devices:
            print(ip, type(ip))
            
            try:
                client_socket = socket.socket()
                client_socket.settimeout(2)
                try:
                    client_socket.connect((ip, self.port))
                    if type(client_socket) != None:
                        client_socket.send('hi'.encode())
                        client_socket.settimeout(None)
                        return client_socket
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
            except socket.error:
                pass
```

When it gets to the correct Ip, it just... times out. Thought I had a problem with the function, but it appeared to not be the case.

TLDR- made a LAN automatic connecting using Nmap, the only thing it's connecting to is timeouts and my sadness D:

Edit: lemme show you the errors which occur when I run this function:

server:

```
    server_socket = socket.socket()
    hostname = socket.gethostname()
    local_ip = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
    server_socket.bind((local_ip,self.port))
```

both sides decide the port which they want to use, i use socket.gethostbyname for server ip.

Comment: not clear what you want

Comment: Hi! What I'm looking for is an answer to why it just times out, and what can i do about it

Comment: even it does not timeout, does your code make any sense?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by that... could you ask again?

Comment: in my opinion google `python socket example` and you'll get a lot of **working** code, why write from scratch by yourself?

Comment: This is not completely from scratch. Used Nmap examples for build this function. and I tried connecting with the bare bones of a client-socket in the local network, it simply doesnt connect and then errors out on the client side with WinError 10060

Comment: please remove un-related code. here timeout has no relationship with nmap, nmap is to find ip address, right? so in your question, you'd better hardcode your valid ip and port.

Comment: Ok, give me a minute and Ill upload the port ip parts

Comment: can you remove nmap related code?

Comment: Removed the nmap part now